# How do I turn a Minus to a - inside user input?

Tags: python, python-3.x, python-2.7, python-requests

I started learning my first real language and can't find a solution for my problem:

how can I convert the user input, if someone is typing minus 10 for example instead of -10?

I just want to convert minus to -

I also added my code.

```
def get_temperatur():
    minus = "-"
    plus = "+"
    while True:
        C = input("Input temperature in Celsius: ")
        try:
            C = float(C)
            return C
        except ValueError:
            print("That is not a valid input")

def convert_to_Kelvin(C):
    K = C +273.15
    return K

if __name__ == "__main__":
    C = get_temperatur()
    print("That is " + str(convert_to_Kelvin(C)) + " Kelvin")

def convert_to_Fahrenheit(C):
    L = C * 1.8
    F = L +32
    return F

if __name__ == "__main__":
    F = get_temperatur()
    print("That is " + str(convert_to_Fahrenheit(F)) + " Fahrenheit")
```

I expect user input minus to be converted to -

Comment: What did you try? Where did that fail? What is your actual problem? This isn't a "solve my problem for me" page.

Comment: I just want to learn how I can write a code, that converts a specific word inside a user input into something else.

Comment: You can use Python replace function to [replace text in a string with a different string](https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/python-string-replace/)

Comment: Are you saying you're trying to solve the case of the user entering 'minus 10' rather than '-10' as the temperature?

Comment: Thank you, that is exactly what I was searching for :)

Comment: Yes exactly that. It's just for learning purposes.

Comment: Also check out [isnumeric](https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/python-string-isnumeric-application/) for checking if a string is numeric as an alternative to your try/catch approach.

Answer (score 1):

Adding - sign will not make it a negative number, It is still going to be a string and you will get ValueError.
Instead do something like,

`if 'minus' in c:
    c = 0 - float(c.split('minus')[1].strip())`

Note: I am assuming that your string will not contains any other word after number. 
i.e. It will be like 'minus 10' and not 'minus 10 xyz'.

Answer (score 1):

```
def get_temperatur():
    minus = "-"
    plus = "+"
    while True:
        C = input("Input temperature in Celsius: ")
        try:
            if 'minus ' in C:
                C = C.replace('minus ', '-')
            C = float(C)
            return C
        except ValueError:
            print("That is not a valid input")
```

The C.replace() function takes in 2 values - the string to be replaced, and what it is to be replaced with. The if statement checks if 'minus '(note the space) is in the string, and if it is, replaces it with '-'

Answer (score 0):

```
def get_temperatur():
    while True:
        C = input("Input temperature in Celsius: ")
        C.replace("minus ", "-")
        try:
            C = float(C)
            return C
        except ValueError:
            print("That is not a valid input")
```